# How to escape - (hyphen) using the groovy language

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, groovyshell

I am trying to declare a variable that requires hyphen as part of the design spec.

```
def user-svc = "accounts"
```

However, i am getting this error -

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php

```
$groovy main.groovy
Hello world
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: user for class: main
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: user for class: main
    at main.run(main.groovy:3)
```

Comment: Wondering why does the design spec specify variable names that aren't valid? ...

Answer (score 2):

Local variable names must be [normal groovy identifiers](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_normal_identifiers), which doesn't include the hyphen.

Though any object property name can consist of arbitrary characters, when using [quoted identifiers](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_quoted_identifiers) or subscript operator:

```groovy
def m = [:]
m.'user-svc' = "accounts"
println m.'user-svc'
println m['user-svc']
```